# Creating a submenu

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, menu, submenu

I want to make a sub menu like this Mozilla Firefox sub menu:

[image: Firefox->View->Toolbars]

This is what it is like now (in my program):

[image: Program->Menu->Sub Menu]

But I want it to look like Firefox were it has an additional menu when you have your mouse over it.

```
#define ID_SM 1

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd,
                                  UINT message,
                                  WPARAM wParam,
                                  LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
            HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();

            AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenu, "Menu");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, ID_SM, "Sub Menu");

            /* Would I put it here? How? */

            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_SM) {
                /* Not sure if this should be here,
                   cause I want it to pop up when you mouse over */
            } 
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just create another menu and append it as a sub-menu. You can do this by calling the same [`AppendMenu` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616.aspx), you just need to set the `uFlags` parameter to `MF_POPUP` and pass the handle to the submenu as the `uIDNewItem` parameter.

For example, something like:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    HMENU hMenubar = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenu, "Menu");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, ID_SM, "Sub Menu");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, "Sub-Sub Menu");

    SetMenu(hwnd, hMenubar);
    break;
```

You don't need to do anything special in response to the `WM_COMMAND` message. Windows will automatically display the pop-up menu when you mouse over the parent menu item. You will, of course, need to handle the commands of the items displayed *on* the sub-menu, however.

Answer (score 6):

First, create a new menu and add items to it. For example:

```
HMENU hSubmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
// Insert or append items to hSubmenu here
```

Then append the created menu into hMenu:

```
AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)hSubmenu, "My Submenu");
```